# Correct, "full length" left-right arrows in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Consider the following simple example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax.plot([0],[0])
ax.grid()
ax.set_xlim([0,10])
ax.set_ylim([0,10])
ax.annotate("", (2, 1), (4, 1), arrowprops={'arrowstyle':'<->'})
plt.show()
```

So, with the `ax.annotate`, I want to draw an arrow from point (x=2, y=1) to point (x=4, y=1); however the output is this:

[image: matplotlib plot]

As visible on the screenshot, the arrowheads do not come to exactly the endpoints (x=2, y=1) and (x=4, y=1) - but instead, there is a small amount of whitespace "padding" or "margin".

How can I have the arrow endpoints (the tips of the arrowheads) to align exactly with the stated endpoints? To make it explicit, I tried editing the image above, and manually drawing the arrowheads (in read) where I'd want them to be:

[image: arrowheads]

---

Thanks to comment by @JodyKlymak, I looked into https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/annotations.html - the only thing that I found obviously related to my problem here was the "shrink" parameter, however, this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax.plot([0],[0])
ax.grid()
ax.set_xlim([0,10])
ax.set_ylim([0,10])
ax.annotate("", (2, 1), (4, 1), arrowprops={'arrowstyle':'<->', 'shrink': 0})
plt.show()
```

... fails with:

```
AttributeError: 'FancyArrowPatch' object has no property 'shrink'
```

I found finally this: [Using arrowstyle causes "Unknown property shrink" · Issue #3697 · matplotlib/matplotlib](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3697):

> Ah, the problem is that if you use the `simple` arrow style which, it turns out, completely changes the code path that is taken. If 'arrowstyle' is in the dictionary then the `arrowprops` dictionary is used to create a `FancyArrow` patch. If `arrowstyle` is *not* in `arrowprops` than the dictionary is used to create a `YAArrow` object.

OK, so trying this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax.plot([0],[0])
ax.grid()
ax.set_xlim([0,10])
ax.set_ylim([0,10])
ax.annotate("", (2, 1), (4, 1), arrowprops={'shrink': 0})
plt.show()
```

... and this does indeed pass - however it draws a completely different, "leftwards" arrow (instead of a left-right arrow):

[image: matplotlib leftward arrow]

So, let me reformulate - is it possible to get "correct" full-length arrow, with the default left-right arrow from ax.annotate (the one that looks just like a line, and not as a thicker filled surface)?

Comment: This is explicitly discussed in the docs: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/annotations.html

Comment: Thanks @JodyKlymak - I just looked through that page, but I don't see where it is explicitly discussed; the only think that I could parse is that there is a "shrink" argument, but when I try it in the code above, `ax.annotate("", (2, 1), (4, 1), arrowprops={'arrowstyle':'<->', 'shrink': 0})`, it fails with "AttributeError: 'FancyArrowPatch' object has no property 'shrink'".

Comment: Did you check https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch.html ? There, the parameter is called `shrinkA` and `shrinkB`. Probably to control start and end independently.

Comment: Thanks @JohanC - indeed, `shrinkA` and `shrinkB` work.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I finally got it; the piece of information I was missing from https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/annotations.html, is that there are several classes that can be used for arrows; and I guess that the definitive list would be the list of Matplotlib patch classes:

https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/patches_api.html

So, we have:

- `matplotlib.patches.Arrow` - "*An arrow patch. Draws an arrow from (x, y) to (x + dx, y + dy). The width of the arrow is scaled by width.*"

Note that the doc text for `Arrow`, never explicitly states, this this is "one-way" arrow - either "leftwards" or "rightwards" arrow. However, that is hinted in a comment at https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Arrow.html :

> See also
>
> FancyArrow - Patch that allows independent control of the head and tail properties.

Well, I guess this is what I'd need - although, I'd say the documentation is inconsistent here, because https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/patches_api.html states:

> - [Arrow](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Arrow.html#matplotlib.patches.Arrow)(x, y, dx, dy[, width]) - An arrow patch.
> - [FancyArrow](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.FancyArrow.html#matplotlib.patches.FancyArrow)(x, y, dx, dy[, width, ...]) - Like Arrow, but lets you set head width and head height independently.
> - [FancyArrowPatch](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch.html#matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch)([posA, posB, path, ...]) - A fancy arrow patch.

So, is `FancyArrow` "Patch that allows independent control of the head and tail properties", or "Like Arrow, but lets you set head width and head height independently"?

Thankfully, I did not have to determine an answer to that, because I finally realized that `FancyArrowPatch` is the class that allows independent control of the head and tail properties - because it has `shrinkA` and `shrinkB` properties; and indeed this works:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax.plot([0],[0])
ax.grid()
ax.set_xlim([0,10])
ax.set_ylim([0,10])
ax.annotate("", (2, 1), (4, 1), arrowprops={'arrowstyle':'<->', 'shrinkA': 0, 'shrinkB': 0})
plt.show()
```

... and indeed - finally - this generates the arrow that I wanted:

[image: Matplotlib leftright arrow]

Comment: I agree it is confusing that there are different kwargs depending on the arrow style!

Comment: yes, that had to be this. great.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use shrink with 'arrowstyle':'<->' as you mentioned.
However, you can use duplicate of ax.annotate("", (2, 1), (4, 1), arrowprops={'shrink': 0}) as in:

```
ax.annotate("", (2, 1), (4, 1), arrowprops={'width': 0.01,'facecolor':'black','shrink': 0})
ax.annotate("", (4, 1), (2, 1), arrowprops={'width': 0.01,'facecolor':'black','shrink': 0})
```

which results in:
[image]

Comment: Thanks - that in principle should work - however, I'd rather not draw two arrows, in order to get one arrow.