# Why does pprint show a different class from print?

Tags: python

Consider this example, adapted from [Correct, "full length" left-right arrows in Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70243684/):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pprint

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax.plot([0],[0])
ax.grid()
ax.set_xlim([0,10])
ax.set_ylim([0,10])
ret = ax.annotate("", (2, 1), (4, 1), arrowprops={'arrowstyle':'<->', 'shrinkA': 0, 'shrinkB': 0})
print("print ret: {}".format(ret))            # print ret: Annotation(2, 1, '')
pprint.pprint("print ret: {}".format(ret))    # "print ret: Annotation(2, 1, '')"
print(ret)                                    # Annotation(2, 1, '')
pprint.pprint(ret)                            # Text(4, 1, '')
plt.show()
```

So, pretty much all printouts of the `ret` variable consider it as of class `Annotation` - except if I put `ret` directly in `pprint`, in which case I get a different class, `Text`. I find that a bit inconsistent, because I'd expect every printout of the variable to result with the same class name.

Is this expected behavior of `pprint` - and if so, why does it happen?

This was on MINGW64 python:

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.9.7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use string formatting, implicit string conversion is applied.
class `Annotation` has [`__str__()` method defined](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/9765379ce6e7343070e815afc0988874041b98e2/lib/matplotlib/text.py#L1612), but no `__repr__()`.

`pprint()` *prints the formatted representation of object* ([the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint)), so it try to use `Annotation.__repr__()`, but it is not defined so it falls back to parent's [`Text.__repr__()`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/9765379ce6e7343070e815afc0988874041b98e2/lib/matplotlib/text.py#L112) (note that `Annotation` inherits from `Text`)

You can compare the result of `str(ret)` and `repr(ret)`.